# why sometimes my EXTJS Web application become unresponsive on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, extjs4.2, cometd, bayeux

We are facing some bizarre issue with our web application when we run it on chrome. All the operations on the application executes as expected but on some days when we execute very basic and common features of the application, chrome starts displaying this pop-up stating  : -
      "The following page has become unresponsive. You can wait for it to become responsive or kill it. With two options of Wait and Kill."

So we are wondering, why sometimes application showing this unexpected behavior. So need your help to figure out what could be possible cause of this.

Little Application Background :
  1. Analytics application so having multiple tabs with multiple charts and Grids on each tabs.
  2. A DOM intensive application with operations on large data.
  3. Developed using EXTJs -4.2 for complete UI and JAVA for the Backend,
  4. CometD as Messaging server.
  4. Appplication deployed on Jetty server.

So we have figured out few areas which could have been causing problems but having hard time to identify exact cause. 
Possible areas of concern : 
1. Rendering of charts, grids and other UI component on Chorme.
2. Slow internet or network by application accessed.
3. Heavy request to the sever  and heavy response data from the server.

So any thoughts what could be causing this possible.
Also are there any tools or plugins etc. which can be useful to identify exact problematic area.

Answer (score 2):

You need to profile your client application and see what script takes so long and why.

Chrome, Firefox, etc. all give nice developer tools to profile scripts, so should be easy to catch what's going on, see for example https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/.

A wild guess could be that if the server replies with a lot of data, this takes a lot of time to process, so Chrome is complaining.

You should look into processing the data in web workers, and/or using `setTimeout` to batch UI updates, see also:

[Avoiding the "script is running too long" dialog, should I split up my function and run it at intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830577/avoiding-the-script-is-running-too-long-dialog-should-i-split-up-my-function)

[How to prevent "Stop running this Script" in browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403448/how-to-prevent-stop-running-this-script-in-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

This also happens if you are making synchronous server calls which are taking more time.